# How to find unclosed html tags or make the weird styling as a result contained in one element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a tinyMCE editor that allows HTML.

Sometimes a user pastes a table from a website or some other content that is not copied in its entirety, resulting in broken html.

I display this content on a page which breaks sometimes due to this. Example image:

[image]

What is the best way to fix this? Is there a way to isolate this html somehow so the content of this element does not affect the rest of the page? Or is there a function to automatically close all tags?

I just simply display the content like this:

```
<div class="editwindow">
    <h4 class="mt-0 m-b-30 header-title bigheader">'.$gettopcatcontent['title'].'</h4>
    <div class="content_tekst">'.$gettopcatcontent['content'].'</div>
    '.$versiondate.'
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you aren't sanitising this content at all, the user can also include JavaScript to run on your page, including code to scrape out everything the user types in and send it to another server. Be sure that you trust the users who have that ability!

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah I am aware of this, but this is not an issue with these users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). It will produce warnings for malformed HTML.

Set [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) to `true` and then use [`libxml_get_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) to handle the warnings.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [W3C Markup Validator Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Thanks but having to do this manually everytime anyone adds a text is not really a good solution.

Comment: You can use the api from W3C Service [Using the W3C Markup Validator API](https://validator.w3.org/docs/users.html#Calling)